# Dart - Polymer Unit Testing. Not able to reference dom elements after click event

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

```
Not able to reference dom elements.
```

Most of the test case works except for the last expectation in `ClickSignInButton` when I want to make sure I can evaluate error message div when form is submitted without any data.

`expect(document.querySelector('qme-header').shadowRoot
                .querySelector('#headerErrorDiv'), isNotNull);` always fails and `headerErrorDiv` is null even though its there in the div.

Code:

```
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';

main() {
   initPolymer().then((zone) => zone.run(() {
     return Polymer.onReady.then((_) {
       group('Header Form Elements Are Available', () {
         test(("CheckSignInFormItems"), () {
            expect(querySelector('qme-header').shadowRoot
            .querySelector('#emailField'), isNotNull);
            expect(querySelector('qme-header').shadowRoot
             .querySelector('#passwordField'), isNotNull);
            expect(querySelector('qme-header').shadowRoot
             .querySelector('#signInButton'), isNotNull);
          });
          test(("CheckRegisterForgotItems"), () {
            expect(querySelector('qme-header').shadowRoot
              .querySelector('#registerButton'), isNotNull);
            expect(querySelector('qme-header').shadowRoot
              .querySelector('#forgotButton'), isNotNull);
          });
         });

         group('Header Form Click Sign In Button', () {
           test(("ClickSignInButton"), () {
             (querySelector('qme-header').shadowRoot
             .querySelector('#emailField') as InputElement).value = "";
            (querySelector('qme-header').shadowRoot
              .querySelector('#passwordField') as InputElement).value =  
                "";

           Timer.run(expectAsync(() {
            (querySelector('qme-header').shadowRoot
            .querySelector('#signInButton') as ButtonElement).click();
            expect(document.querySelector('qme-header').shadowRoot
             .querySelector('#headerErrorDiv'), isNotNull);
          }));
         });
       });
      });
     }));
   }
```

Hi Günter, Thank you for your time, I adjusted my code based on your comments and it should work, however I think I am messing up the way I am using polymer templates.

### pubspec.yaml

```
   environment:
          sdk: '>=1.0.0 <2.0.0'
   dependencies:
          bootstrap: ^3.3.4
          browser: '>=0.10.0 <0.11.0'
          polymer: '>=0.16.0 <0.17.0'
          test: '>=0.12.3'
    transformers:
        - polymer:
            inline_stylesheets:
               packages/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css: false
               packages/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css: false
            entry_points:
              - web/index.html
              - test/qme_header_test.html
         - test/pub_serve:
              $include: test/**_test{.*,}.dart
```

### header.html

```
       <polymer-element name="qme-header">
         <div class="container">
             <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand"  
              href="#"><span>QMe Application</span></a></div>
              <template if="{{usingHeaderForm}}">
                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" >
                      <form on-submit="{{validateSignInForm}}" 
               class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                          <div class="form-group">
                               <input type="text" id="emailField" 
               value="{{qmeSignIn.userEmail}}" placeholder="Email" 
               class="form-control">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="password" id="passwordField" 
                value="{{qmeSignIn.userPassword}}"  
                placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
                          </div>
                          <button id="signInButton" type="submit" 
                 class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Sign in</button>
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                          <button id="registerButton" class="btn btn-
                   info btn-xs" type="button-small">Register</button>
                          &nbsp;
                          <button id="forgotButton" class="btn btn-info 
                 btn-xs" type="button-small">Forgot Password</button>
                      </form>
                    </div>
              </template>
              <template if="{{!usingHeaderForm}}">
                    <p>Hello login complete</p>
              </template>
```

### header.dart

```
       library qme_header;

       import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
       import 'dart:html';
       import 'package:qme/views/qme_error.dart';

       @CustomTag('qme-header')
       class QmeHeader extends PolymerElement {
       @published QMeSignIn qmeSignIn;

       @observable bool usingHeaderForm = true;

       @observable QmeErrorHolder qmeErrorHolder;

       QmeHeader.created() : super.created() {
          qmeSignIn = new QMeSignIn();
          qmeErrorHolder = QmeErrorHolder.instance;
        }

        toggleFormDisplay() {
          usingHeaderForm = !usingHeaderForm;
         }

          performLogin() {
           toggleFormDisplay();
           }

          bool validateSignInEmail() {
            if (qmeSignIn.userEmail.length == 0) {
             qmeErrorHolder.headerErrorMessage = "Valid user email 
             required";
             return false;
            }
            qmeErrorHolder.headerErrorMessage = '';
            return true;
           }

           bool validateSignInPassword() {
           if (qmeSignIn.userPassword.length == 0) {
              qmeErrorHolder.headerErrorMessage = "Valid user password 
           required";
            return false;
           }
           qmeErrorHolder.headerErrorMessage = '';
           return true;
           }

         validateSignInForm(Event event, Object detail, Node sender) {
          event.preventDefault();
         if (validateSignInEmail() && validateSignInPassword()) {
          print("Submit");
          performLogin();
           qmeErrorHolder.headerError = false;
          } else {
           qmeErrorHolder.headerError = true;
         }
        }
         }

        class QMeSignIn extends Observable {
            @observable String userEmail;
            @observable String userPassword;
            QMeSignIn([this.userEmail = "", this.userPassword = ""]);
           }
```

### error.html

```
         <polymer-element name="qme-error">
          <template>
           <template if="{{qmeErrorHolder.headerError}}">
             <div class="container">
                  <div id="headerErrorDiv" class="alert alert-danger" 
            role="alert">{{qmeErrorHolder.headerErrorMessage}}</div>
              </div>
            </template>
         </template>
          <script type="application/dart" src="qme_error.dart">
          </script>
         </polymer-element>
```

### error.dart

```
         library qme_error;

         import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

         @CustomTag('qme-error')
         class QmeError extends PolymerElement {
            @observable QmeErrorHolder qmeErrorHolder;

            QmeError.created() : super.created() {
            qmeErrorHolder = QmeErrorHolder.instance;
           }
          }

          class QmeErrorHolder extends Observable {
             @observable bool headerError;

             @observable String headerErrorMessage;

             static final QmeErrorHolder _instance = new    
             QmeErrorHolder._internal();

             static QmeErrorHolder get instance => _instance;

             QmeErrorHolder._internal();
            }
```

### headertest.html

```
            <html>
             <head>
              <link rel="import" 
              href="../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
              <link rel="import"  
              href="../packages/qme/views/qme_header.html" >
               <link rel="import" 
              href="../packages/qme/views/qme_error.html" >
             <link rel="stylesheet" 
              href="packages/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
              <link rel="stylesheet" 
               href="packages/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
                <script type="application/dart" 
               src="qme_header_test.dart"></script>
            <script data-pub-inline src="packages/test/dart.js"> 
              </script>
            </head>
              <body>
                <qme-header></qme-header>
                <qme-error></qme-error>
              </body>
             </html>
```

### headertest.dart

```
             @whenPolymerReady
             void runTests() {

               group('Header Form Click Sign In Button', () {
                   test(("ClickSignInButton"), () {
                 (querySelector('qme-header::shadow #emailField ') as         
                   InputElement).value ="";
             (querySelector(
                  'qme-header::shadow #passwordField') as 
                  InputElement).value = "";
                (querySelector('qme-header::shadow #signInButton') as 
                  ButtonElement)
                  .click();
            expect(
                 document.querySelector('qme-error::shadow #headerErrorDiv'), isNotNull);
            });
           });
              }
```

### index.html

```
          <html>
            <head>
             <link rel="stylesheet" 
               href="packages/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
               <link rel="stylesheet" 
               href="packages/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
             <link rel="import" 
           href="packages/qme/views/qme_header.html">
            <link rel="import" 
             href="packages/qme/views/qme_error.html">
           </head>
              <body>
              <qme-header></qme-header>
                 <qme-error></qme-error>

            <script src="packages/bootstrap/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="packages/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script data-pub-inline src="packages/browser/dart.js">    
             </script>
             <script type="application/dart">export 
             'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
          </body>
            </html>
```

Running `index.html` in Dartium works, however header test fails with null for `headerErrorDiv`. I know I am messing up with Polymer template and having gobal error holder most likely, but it works when `index.html` runs in Dartium and fails test cases when `headertest.html` is run.

Comment: I assume the cause is that `headerErrorDiv` only exists if `qmeErrorHolder.headerError` is `true`. Also see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you Günter, yes changing the test files to _test.html/_test.dart and validating the qmeErrorHolder.headerError is set to true solved the issue. All good now, Thank you for your time.

Comment: Great! if the answer solves your problem can you please accept by clicking the check mark below the up- down-vote buttons, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, I think you should add the `@whenPolymerReady` annotation to `main()` instead of your Polymer initialization code.

Instead of

```
expect(document.querySelector('qme-header').shadowRoot
         .querySelector('#headerErrorDiv'), isNotNull);
```

you could use

```
expect(document.querySelector('qme-header::shadow #headerErrorDiv'), isNotNull);
```

I don't see a problem in your
 cod.  Can you please provide a complete example that allows to reproduce your problem (incl HTML and pubspec.yaml)

`headerErrorDiv` only exists if `qmeErrorHolder.headerError` is true

I think you should ensure the test files end with `_test`(`.dart`|`.html`) to be recognized by the testrunner `pub run test`

You need to change the Dart script tag to `x-link-dart` to make the test work with the testrunner (and back to `<script>` when you want to run it directly)

AFAIK If your test needs additional files like your component files you need to run `pub serve test` and pass the port to `pub run test` (see readme of the test package for more details)